# How to make query fast

Tags: mysql

I'm using below mentioned query with about 400,000 records in each table its taking about 10~12 seconds to give results. Is there any way I can make it faster.

Query:

```
select url_details.title, url_details.summary, url_details.id from urls,
url_details where urls.status='' AND urls.keyword_id='2791' AND
url_details.url_id=urls.id
```

Comment: please post your table create statement! (to see wich engine you use and what kind of keys your defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to almost all mysql performance problems are indexes.
If you know that you'll be filtering on these three variables for all of your queries, add a complex index that spans those three fields.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

If you will have no idea which indexes will be filtered upon, then add a simple index for each field, and rely on mysql's "index merge" optimization.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped a lot. Earlier query was taking about 8~12 sec but not it has come down to 0.00 seconds. Thanks you all :)

Comment: @Prashant: I'm interested in what exactly solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create INDEXES for the key which you normally compare..That will reduce the time drastically

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define the keys on your tables

urls (habe to defined a index with status and keyword_id):

```
ALTER TABLE `urls` ADD INDEX `index_keyword_status`(`keyword_id`, `status`);
```

and urls_details.url_id have to be a foreign key OR a index

your select:

```
SELECT
url_details.title,
url_details.summary,
url_details.id
FROM urls
INNER JOIN url_details
    ON url_details.url_id=urls.id
WHERE urls.keyword_id = 279
    AND LENGTH(urls.status) = 0
```

Comment: Is using length() faster than ='' ? If you have null, what happen? The same?

Comment: @haltabush length is not faster, but it handles null values

Answer (score 0):

First, you should better use join syntax :

```
select url_details.title, url_details.summary, url_details.id from urls join urls_details using(url_id)  where urls.status='' AND urls.keyword_id='2791'
```

You also need to have somes indexes on urls.status, both url_id and keyword_id.
If you have 4 000 000 records on each tables, it will still be a bit slow I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Not only creating Index will solve all issues.
You can optimize your table structure and remove redundant indexes if there are any.
I am using [SQLyog](http://webyog.com) which has 'Query Profiler' which will let you know how does your query execution happened, step-by-step approach to query execution (typical layout will look like this), also it has 'Calculate Optimal Datatypes' and 'Find redundant index' which can let you optimized your table structure, I hope this tool will help you.
 [image])